# Best solutions for a data analytics problem

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy, data-analysis

We have a table of bid prices and sizes of two buyers. Bid price `p` with size `s` means that the buyer is open to buy `s` number of product at price `p`. We have a table of four columns:

- bid prices offered by the two buyers, `pA` and `pB`.
- bid sizes, `sA` and `sB`.
  Our job is to add a new best size column (`bS`) to the table, that returns the size at the best price. If the two buyers have the same price then `bS` is equal to `sA + sB`, otherwise, we need to take the bid size of the buyer that offers the higher price.

One of my solution to the problem is below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
N = 1000 *1000

t = pd.DataFrame({
   'pA': [np.random.randint(0, 5, N)],
   'pB': [np.random.randint(0, 5, N)],
   'sA': [np.random.randint(0, 100, N)],
   'sB': [np.random.randint(0, 100, N)]})

t['bS'] = np.where(t['pA'] == t['pB'], 
             t['sA'] + t['sB'],
             np.where(t['pA'] > t['pB'], 
                      t['sA'], t['sB']))
```

I wrote an article and listed other solutions. I am wondering if I missed anything. Feedback from which we can learn from is very welcome!

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/data-analysis-example-python-q-ferenc-bodon-ph-d-/

Answer (score 1):

Bodon,

I'm curious how this function's performance compares for you.

```
def func2(df):
    list2 = []
    for r in zip(t['pA'],t['pB'],t['sA'],t['sB']):
        if r[0] == r[1]:
            list2.append(r[2] + r[3])
        if r[0] > r[1]:
            list2.append(r[2])
        if r[1] > r[0]:
            list2.append(r[3])
    df['bS'] = list2
    return df
```

This is what I ran on my system and the corresponding results. My go to function was a for loop using `iterrows()`. After checking and realizing it was slower than your `np.where()` I gave `zip()` a try and performance seems slightly faster.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import timeit

N = 1000*1000

t = pd.DataFrame({'pA' : np.random.randint(0,5,size = N),
        'pB' : np.random.randint(0,5,size = N),
        'sA' : np.random.randint(0,100,size = N),
        'sB' : np.random.randint(0,100,size = N)})

t['bS'] = np.where(t['pA'] == t['pB'], 
             t['sA'] + t['sB'],
             np.where(t['pA'] > t['pB'], 
                      t['sA'], t['sB']))

def func1(df):
    list1 = []
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['pA'] == row['pB']:
            list1.append(row['sA'] + row['sB'])
        if row['pA'] > row['pB']:
            list1.append(row['sA'])
        if row['pB'] > row['pA']:
            list1.append(row['sB'])
    df['bS'] = list1
    return df

def func2(df):
    list2 = []
    for r in zip(t['pA'],t['pB'],t['sA'],t['sB']):
        if r[0] == r[1]:
            list2.append(r[2] + r[3])
        if r[0] > r[1]:
            list2.append(r[2])
        if r[1] > r[0]:
            list2.append(r[3])
    df['bS'] = list2
    return df

setup = '''
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import timeit

N = 10

t = pd.DataFrame({'pA' : np.random.randint(0,5,size = N),
        'pB' : np.random.randint(0,5,size = N),
        'sA' : np.random.randint(0,100,size = N),
        'sB' : np.random.randint(0,100,size = N)})

t['bS'] = np.where(t['pA'] == t['pB'], 
             t['sA'] + t['sB'],
             np.where(t['pA'] > t['pB'], 
                      t['sA'], t['sB']))

def func1(df):
    list1 = []
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['pA'] == row['pB']:
            list1.append(row['sA'] + row['sB'])
        if row['pA'] > row['pB']:
            list1.append(row['sA'])
        if row['pB'] > row['pA']:
            list1.append(row['sB'])
    df['bS'] = list1
    return df

def func2(df):
    list2 = []
    for r in zip(t['pA'],t['pB'],t['sA'],t['sB']):
        if r[0] == r[1]:
            list2.append(r[2] + r[3])
        if r[0] > r[1]:
            list2.append(r[2])
        if r[1] > r[0]:
            list2.append(r[3])
    df['bS'] = list2
    return df
'''

timeit.timeit("t['bS'] = np.where(t['pA'] == t['pB'], t['sA'] + t['sB'],np.where(t['pA'] > t['pB'], t['sA'], t['sB']))", setup = setup, number = 1000)
Out[0]: 0.6907481750604347    
timeit.timeit("func1(t)", setup = setup, number = 1000)
Out[1]: 1.7969895842306869
timeit.timeit("func2(t)", setup = setup, number = 1000)
Out[2]: 0.40988909450607025
```

Comment: Hi Angel! I like your approaches - thanks for submitting them. The test results provide some surprising insights. It would be good to understand all the performance aspects of the three solutions.

Comment: You're most welcome Ferenc. What surprising insights are you referring to?